# How to visualize nodes in horizontal cluster with invisible edges (Python diagrams)

Tags: python, graphviz, diagram

I'm trying to make a horizontal cluster containing two nodes (here visualized as users) in Python module [diagrams](https://diagrams.mingrammer.com/) which uses Graphviz for rendering.

But the only way to achieve this is by adding edges between the nodes.

#### Horizontal, but with edge shown between nodes

```py
from diagrams import Cluster, Diagram
from diagrams.onprem.client import User

with Diagram("sample", show=False) as diag:
    with Cluster("sample horizontal cluster with edge"):
        node1 = User("Some Node")
        node2 = User("Some other Node")
        node1 >> node2
```

Which produces:

[image]

#### Without edge, but vertical

I've tried without the connection `node1 >> node2`:

```py
    with Cluster("sample horizontal cluster with edge", direction="LR"):
        node1 = User("Some Node")
        node2 = User("Some other Node")
```

Then it renders vertically, which I don't want:
[image]

I don't want to see that edge but have the nodes arranged horizontally.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [example from *Edges* guide](https://diagrams.mingrammer.com/docs/guides/edge) and connect with an **invisible edge** using `style="invis"` like supported by GraphViz's [`style` atrribute](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/style/):

```
from diagrams import Cluster, Diagram, Edge
from diagrams.onprem.client import User

with Diagram("invisible_edge", show=False) as diag:
    with Cluster("sample horizontal cluster with invisible edge"):
        node1 = User("Some Node")
        node2 = User("Some other Node")
        node1 - Edge(style='invis') - node2
```

Renders using GraphViz to:
[image: nodes connected using invisible edge]